# MS SQL SERVER Reading large data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring

Hi I use MS SQL Server 2016 and I need to read large data.
I want use adaptive buffering to read first for example 1000 rows.

My procedure retrun 1 milion rows but I dont want out of memory my application so I want to read data by adaptive buffering.
I saw only for long data columns but I want this for rows. Could you help me?

Comment: What on earth can your application possibly do with a million rows even if they could all be returned immediately? Look up `SQL Server pagination`. Pagination is how Google shows you 10 results at a time instead of [all 3,660,000 results at once](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+pagination), and this site shows you 15 results at a time instead of [over 1,000 in one screen](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+pagination).

Comment: My application want call once procedure and create csv file with whole data. I don't want rewrite my file

Answer (score 0):

Your application and users don't want a million rows. Why would your procedure try to return them all? You want to use [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20pagination%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3afalse).

For example, in SQL Server you can do this using `OFFSET`/`FETCH`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PageByPage
  @PageNumber int = 1,
  @PerPage    int = 100
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  WITH the_keys AS
  (
    SELECT key_column
      FROM dbo.table_name
      ORDER BY key_column
      OFFSET @PerPage * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
      FETCH NEXT @PerPage ROWS ONLY
  )
  SELECT t.all_columns ...
    FROM dbo.table_name AS t
    INNER JOIN the_keys AS k 
      ON t.key_column = k.key_column
    ORDER BY t.key_column;
END
GO
```

Now your application keeps track of which page you're on, and passes the next or previous page as the user navigates through pages.

The reason for the CTE is to make the initial search as narrow as possible, since your actual query probably is more complex (Aaron Bertrand talks about this approach [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)).

Comment: My application want call once procedure and create csv file with whole data. I don't want rewrite my file. Can I use something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-adaptive-buffering?view=sql-server-ver15